# Vuetify fixed FAB overflows the content

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I've started a new Nuxt project with Vuetify and added a FAB to one of the pages.

I'm still using the basic layout that comes out of the box.

I've added the following to my page's template:

```
<v-btn fab bottom right fixed color="primary">
```

And what I get is:
[image]

where the black part is the footer defined in the layout.

I want this button to be fixed at but above the footer.
I found this css rule:

```
.v-btn--absolute.v-btn--bottom, .v-btn--fixed.v-btn--bottom {
bottom: 16px;
```

}

and I can override it to a higher value, yet I'm not sure that's the best solution, and if so where to do it.

Here's my layout:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      :mobile-break-point="mobileBreakPoint"
      clipped
      fixed
      app
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="(item, i) in items"
          :key="i"
          :to="item.to"
          nuxt
          exact
        >
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title v-text="item.title" />
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-app-bar clipped-left fixed app>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        class="hidden-lg-and-up"
        @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"
      />
      <v-toolbar-title v-text="title" />
      <v-spacer />
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
        <nuxt />
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer fixed app style="background: black;">
      <span>&copy; {{ new Date().getFullYear() }}</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Maybe it's something with the layout? my end goal is to wrap all pages with footer, app bar and navigation.

Thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue, overcame it with a direct style `:style="{bottom: '16px'}` for the button, but that does seem very nice. Hope someone answers and explains the cause for this